# SFMC Mobile push filtering logic issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, mobilepush-ios, push-notification

Seems that the SFMC creates the broadcasting list on contact basis instead of device basis.
So if the user has several devices connected to him in the SFMC service then the filtering function opts all of the user's devices instead of opting only the devices that meet the filtering condition.

**Example:**

Imagine that MobilePush demographics data extension have some custom boolean attribute `Switcher`.

Imagine that some user has 2 devices with the same SFMC-charged app, let them be `device A` and `device B`.

The `device A`'s app has custom attribute `Switcher` value set to `True`.

The `device B`'s app has custom attribute `Switcher` value set to `False`.
Both of devices are connected to the user in the SFMC system by setting the same subscriber key.

Imagine that the MobilePush service has filtering list `SwitcherFilteringList` which has the condition: `Switcher equals True`.

When I'm trying to send a push message using `SwitcherFilteringList`, the SFMC system takes the user's contact and sends the push notification to the `device A` and the `device B`. But it should send the push-notification to the `device A` only.

Does anybody have any idea how to resolve this issue?